# TWRP: compress files using file manager

Tags: twrp

I checked the TWRP 3.1.0.0 file manager and it didn't have the option to compress files; I've also checked [AROMA File Manager](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1646108) and it lacked it too.

My question is, since twrp can work win zip files (flashing roms, ...) it seems logical to suppose that it can handle compressed files, then is there any possibility so that we can compress files or folders (possibly from internal storage) while in twrp recovery?

Comment: It's not available in the [command line](https://twrp.me/faq/openrecoveryscript.html) of TWRP, so I don't think it's possible

Comment: @beeshyams Actually, while TWRP's terminal lacks `zip`, it still has `tar`, `gzip` and `xz`, so support for compressing is present.